# Google Apps device policy in Android

Tags: android, device-admin

How to use Google Apps device policy in Android.
what are the methods we need to use to provide google apps device policy in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to some basic [official documentation](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190930) (also take a look [here](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1056433)). Being a security product, you cannot directly (in code) implement changes for GADP on your device.